# Connect to Redis using TIBCO BusinessWorks 5

Tags: java, redis, tibco, tibco-business-works

I wanna connect to a Redis Cluster via TIBCO BW5, So far I've no idea where to start!

Is there a way to connect via JDBC or should I write my own custom Java code?

So far I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest path to Redis integration via JDBC is through Redis SQL - https://github.com/redis-field-engineering/redis-sql-trino

> Redis SQL Trino lets lets you easily integrate with visualization
> frameworks — like Tableau and SuperSet — and platforms that support
> JDBC-compatible databases (e.g., Mulesoft). Query support includes
> SELECT statements across secondary indexes on both Redis hashes &
> JSON, aggregations (e.g., count, min, max, avg), ordering, and more.

However, if you want to build your own integration then [TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks™ Plug-in Development Kit (PDK)](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-activematrix-businessworks-plug-in-development-kit-6-3-1) could be the way.